# Angular 2: Why do I need classes like Hero.ts?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am a web developer coming from Angular 1.3. Now I'm learning Angular 2 and there is one thing I can't get clear:

When I have a page where I can view heroes, I would have a controller and a service to get the data e.g. from a REST-API in Angular1.

In Angular2 I have the component, a service and a **Hero class**. Why do I need that class 'Hero'?

What are the advantages in comparison to just using objects like in Angular1? Is it best practice to implement a class for every object I use in my application?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What `Hero` class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's the `Hero` class from https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt1.html then it's just the data the component is working with (display, edit, ...)

As mentioned in the comments. If concrete classes are used you get full benefit of the static type checking capabilities of TypeScript and related tools.

Comment: Yep, I think this is the one the OP is referencing. It's just a more complete way of displaying something instead of just ":any". You can do a lot more with the class than an object. OP, check out the TypeScript docs to get a more complete understanding of TypeScript vs JavaScript, rather than Angular 1 vs 2... https://www.typescriptlang.org/ -- EDIT: feel free to move this into your answer, btw

Comment: @user3745073 consider how your tests will look later, or when you're writing some code to manipulate the values of the "Hero". Wouldn't it be nicer if it was type-checked?

Comment: Ok so they are mainly for testing and type-checking. Got it - thanks!

Comment: Type-checking - yes. Not sure what you mean with "testing". Using types instead of anonymous object literals allows TS to find bugs by checking if you are accessing properties for methods that type actually doesn't have before you even run the application and it provides better auto-completion. It's just more like languages like Java, C#, C++, Delphi, ... do it since decades.